# Android test involving application restart

Tags: android, android-testing

I am trying to implement a background job queue. The job queue should be persistent. 
That is, if the android decide to terminate my application, destroying the process, the jobs need to be retrieved (from database) and resumed when next launch of my application.

I want to test this feature by using the android test framework. By looking through the documentation, I can not find a way to setup this scenario which involves application restart.

More specifically, I want to simulate:

1. Create job queue, add jobs.
2. Application go into background.
3. Android decide to terminate application, ending the process, job queue deallocated
4. Application restart, job queue retrieved and resumed

Answer (score 0):

In Android 4.0+ you have option "**Don't keep activities**" in settings/developer options - this way you can simulate a situation Android OS kills your app.

Comment: I can do this test on device. However I want to write it as a TestCase and execute it in the test framework